# Wifi selective proxy server

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

I use Dropbox to backup files on my 12.04 laptop. Currently, whenever Dropbox has an internet connection it syncs. This is an issue when I am tethering with my mobile because of the cost of mobile data.

The Dropbox application doesn't let me choose which wifi networks to use but I can use a proxy server. So I was thinking I could setup a local proxy server with wifi rules.

Does anyone know of a proxy server which has network rules based on wifi? Or does anyone have a better option for limiting Dropbox to particular wifi networks? Apart from simply closing Dropbox ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with the proxies, but you can use UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) to redirect the outbound traffic. You can start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW and here's how you can redirect inbound traffic: https://serverfault.com/questions/238563/can-i-use-ufw-to-setup-a-port-forward.

Comment: Cheers mate, I was hoping for a simpler solution but this will work :)